# How can I find the probability of a value occuring in an interval of a given step function?

Tags: probability, functions

Knowing a step function $N(t)$ defined over the interval $[0,T]$, which takes values in $0, 1, ..., k$, how can I define the probability $p(n)$ for $0 \leq n \leq k$, which is the probability of a random $x$ in $[0,T]$ having $N(x)=n$. In other words, how can I find the proportion of $x$'s in my interval that map to $n$?

Example:
If $N(t):[0,3]$, $N(t)=0$ for $0\leq t \leq 1$ and $N(t) = 1$ for $1 < t \leq3$, then $p(0) = 1/3, p(1) = 2/3$.

Edit: fixed wrong interval

Comment: $1<t≤3$, Shouldn't that be a 2 instead of 3?